# How to implement in-batch negative sampling in Pytorch?

Tags: pytorch, sampling

I tried to train Two-tower model for recommender system using implicit dataset.
Before training, I want to preprocess dataset using in-batch negative sampling.
I think code is well, but performance is really slow, so I can't train the model.
Can you check the training method?

```py
def train_with_in_batch_negative_sampling(
    model,
    num_epoch,
    optimizer,
    data_loader,
    criterion,
    device,
    log_interval=10,
    num_neg_samples=5,
):
    model.train()
    total_loss = 0
    train_loss = 987654321
    tk0 = tqdm.tqdm(data_loader, smoothing=0, mininterval=1.0)

    for i, (fields, target) in enumerate(tk0):
        fields, target = fields.to(device), target.to(device)
        new_fields = []
        for idx, row in enumerate(fields):
            if idx==0:
                item_tensor = fields[idx+1:,1]
            else:
                item_tensor = torch.cat([fields[:idx,1], fields[idx+1:,1]],dim=0)
            new_fields.append(torch.Tensor([row[0], row[1], torch.Tensor(1)]).view(1, -1).to(device))
            new_fields.append(
                torch.cat(
                    [
                        row[0:1].repeat(511).view(-1, 1),
                        item_tensor.view(-1, 1),
                        torch.zeros(511, 1).to(device),
                    ],
                    dim=1,
                )
            )
        merged = torch.cat(new_fields,dim=0).to(torch.int)
        y = model(merged[:,:2])
        loss = criterion(y, merged[:,2])
        model.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        total_loss += loss.item()
        train_loss = min(train_loss, total_loss / log_interval)
        if (i + 1) % log_interval == 0:
            tk0.set_postfix(loss=total_loss / log_interval, epoch_num=num_epoch)
        total_loss = 0
    return train_loss
```

I tried negative random sampling before creating Dataloader, but the trained result is not quite well. So I want to apply in-batch negative sampling.

Comment: Do you have gpu? I think it would be better to do data preprocessing on cpu, try not use .to(device) before `merged = torch.cat(new_fields,dim=0).to(torch.int)` line.

Comment: @Junyeong Did you ever figure out an efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the approach in [tfrs](https://github.com/tensorflow/recommenders/blob/28a28f02e524f14f3e6facd9e276cc82bbb719df/tensorflow_recommenders/tasks/retrieval.py#L156)
At least it gives some insight